# How to display the nth child of a Model?

Tags: html, laravel, laravel-blade

How should i display my model correctly on my page? I have this model `Process` that **hasOne** `Person` and a person **hasMany**  `Training`, so in my `ProcessController@show` i have this:

```php
$process = Process::where('id', $process->id)->with(['person'])->firstOrFail();
dd($process->person->trainings);
```

on that die&dump it output all Training data that belongs to that particular person but my problem is on this page(`show.blade.php` of my process), it doesn't show my data:

```html
<table class="table4 display compact">
    <tr style="line-height: 5px;">
        <th style="display: none;">Id</th>
        <th>Training</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th width="30px;"></th>
    </tr>
    @if ($process->person && count($process->person->trainings) > 0)
    @foreach ($process->person->trainings as $training)
    <tr class="hide" style="line-height: 5px;">
        <td style="display: none;">{{ $training->id }}</td>
        <td contenteditable="false">{{ $training->training_name }}</td>
        <td contenteditable="false">{{ $training->description }}</td>
        <td>
            <!--span class="table-remove4 glyphicon glyphicon-remove"><i class="fas fa-minus-circle"></i></span-->
        </td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
    @else
    <tr class="hide" style="line-height: 10px;">
        <td style="display: none;"></td>
        <td contenteditable="true"></td>
        <td contenteditable="true"></td>
        <td>
            <span class="table-remove4 glyphicon glyphicon-remove"><i class="fas fa-minus-circle"></i></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    @endif
</table>
```

Comment: It doesn't show because you put the `hide` class in the `tr` tag. Try to remove the `hide` class

Comment: Oh, indeed thanks for pointing me that. I did not notice.